# EXIF component that could write data to JPG files (Delphi7)

Tags: delphi, components, edit, exif

I'm looking for a component, for Delphi7, that can write EXIF data to JPG images.

I often make panoramas, joining some pictures I shot with my camera. PTGui is the program I use to make such panoramas. The problem is EXIF data from the original pictures don't be retained at the final image.

I'd like to write a code, using Delphi7,  that reads EXIF data from the first image of the set and write that data to the final panorama image.

I could find CCR EXIF, but it's from Delphi 2006 ahead, not D7...

Anyone could suggest some idea, tip, clue?

---

**Edited**:
I'm very sorry to put a question considered off-topic. Of course it wasn't my intent.

Answering and thanking Warren P, yes, I tried CCR with Delphi7.

Trying any of its sample codes, return this error:
`Constant expression expected.`

at this line:
    `{$IF CompilerVersion < 23}    //no FMX before XE2`

in `CCR.Exif.inc` file

There are three kinds of sample:

- with 2009 at the end of filename
- with XE at the end of filename
- just filename

---

This small code returns a missing DCU file:

```
uses 
  CCR.Exif;

procedure ReadCameraMakeAndModel(const FileName: string;
  out Make, Model: string);
var
  ExifData: TExifData;
begin
  ExifData := TExifData.Create;
  try
    ExifData.LoadFromGraphic(FileName);
    Make := ExifData.CameraMake;
    Model := ExifData.CameraModel;
  finally
    ExifData.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

`File not found: CCR.Exif.dcu`

There is no DCU file in DCU folder.

Because of above errors I concluded that CCR Exif is not for Delphi 7, but I may be wrong.

---

**Edited 2**
Updating some info:

I installed Delphi 2007, supposed to be able to compile CCR Exif.
But I'm facing a strange behaviour when trying to compile some Samples project that comes along CCR Exif. I can compile the following Samples:
`IPTCEditor`
`XMPBrowser`

But I cannot compile the following:
`ExifList`
`JpegDump`
`ResaveTest`
`Screenshot`
`TimeShift`

The error is the same for all of them:

At this block:

```
if Value <> LastSetDateTimeValue then
  begin
    LastSetDateTimeValue := Value;
    LastSetDateTimeMainStr := DateTimeToExifString(Value);
    LastSetDateTimeSubSecStr := GetExifSubSecsString(Value);
  end;
```

Errors:

```
[DCC Error] CCR.Exif.pas(2475): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDateTime' and 'TDateTimeTagValue'
[DCC Error] CCR.Exif.pas(4410): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDateTime' and 'TDateTimeTagValue'
[DCC Error] CCR.Exif.pas(4411): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDateTime' and 'TDateTimeTagValue'
[DCC Error] ExifList.dpr(17): F2063 Could not compile used unit '..\..\CCR.Exif.pas'
```

The weird thing is that I have a friend who has **Delphi XE** but he can compile the Samples **without error**... :-(

Searching CCR.Exif.BaseUtils.pas I found **DateTimeTagValue** as **record**. But why my friend can compile the very same package??? And I can't?

Here, a screenshot of my desk layout:

[image]
Someone has a clue?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a product recommendation site or link referral engine. Google and Bing both specialize in searching for things and returning links to the search results. Good luck.

Comment: Just because ccr-exif says "delphi 2006 ahead" are you really sure it doesn't work with Delphi 7? Did you even TRY it? If you try it and can't figure out how to backport it, a specific question like "how to write this so it compiles in Delphi 7" (with a single line of code in question) might be on topic.